# Folder to an application

Tags: windows, user-interface, folderbrowserdialog

I apologize upfront for butchering the verbiage. Here is what I am trying to figure out.

I work with projects that currently use windows folders to store project files (500-1000) per project. The current interaction with a project is clicking through folders and opening individual files. There are also a lot of macros already in use in the various excel workbooks.

I would like to create a desktop "application" that stores files but also runs script, basically cleaning up the project interface and turning the project folder structure into a single desktop "object".

1. The "application" would open an interface (such as a vba user form) when double-clicked.
2. The "application" would contain the project files (excel, word, pdf, etc.)
3. The interface would be used to navigate through the contained files and update the various files in the "application" with user input data.
4. The "application" could be "cracked open" to see the files inside in windows explorer (similar to how .exe can be changed to .zip)

I've not been able to find anything that matches what I'm looking for so any that points me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.